# Qtcreator on Mac OS can't see std when using cmake and openmp

Tags: qt-creator, clang++

If I have a project with this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(myproject LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(myexe main.cpp)

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myexe PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

And the following code in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Hi\n";
}
```

The project actually builds and runs just fine. But the IDE itself is broken and can't find the std headers. And as a result it has red squiggly lines under everything std related. In our example it will look like this:

[image: red squiggly lines under iostream and std::cout]

This issue only happens when I use OpenMP in CMakeLists.txt

In the "General Messages" tab I'm getting the following error:

```
Compiler feature detection failure!
The command "/usr/bin/clang++ -fPIE -fopenmp -std=gnu++17 -x c++ -E -v - -target x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0" terminated with exit code 1.
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

So I'm pretty sure that's related. How do I fix this? Halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't understand what causes that issue but I figured out how to solve it.

We'll have to use the llvm clang.

```
brew install llvm
```

That will install clang and clang++ compilers at `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/`.

We'll have to make sure that qtcreator uses the llvm compiler instead of the one at `/usr/bin/clang++`. And we do that by making a new kit that uses the new compiler and configure the project to use that new kit instead.

- Qtcreator > Preferences > Kits > Compilers
- Add > Clang > C
- Give it a some name like: `llvm clang`, and its path at `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`
- Add > Clang > C++
- Give it a some name like: `llvm clang++`, and its path at `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`
- Qtcreator > Preferences > Kits > Kits
- Add
- Give it a some name like: `llvm clang`, and choose the `llvm clang` and `llvm clang++` for the C and C++ compilers respectively.

And the last step would be to have your project use the new kit instead.

- On the Projects tab on the left side
- Build & Run
- Choose the `llvm clang` kit

And that will be all! Hope that helps :)